# slf4j implementation conflicts

Tags: slf4j

My tests fail because of

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.10 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6, 1.7]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
```

I discovered that I can add the following implementation to resolve this conflict.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

However, I am wondering how to figure out which depedency brings 1.5.10. When running `mvn dependency:tree` I only get my slf4j-api listed.

**EDIT**

Ok, I figured out why it's not listed: One of my dependencies implements a Logger itself. However, I am still unsure how I could have figured that out BEFORE adding the slf4j-simple dependency. But I guess that has nothing to do with maven.

Comment: Please show us more of your POM file. Specifically, all the dependencies that relate to SLF4J.

Comment: @rweng Can you please post your pom.xml ?